# Contradictory results when determine the Coefficients of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Suppose we have a equation
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(nx)
\end{equation}
and we need to find $a_n$. Here $f(x)$ is a smooth odd function defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$. The answer is
\begin{equation}
a_n=\frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(nx)\mathrm{d}x}
\end{equation}
by using
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)\sin(nx)\mathrm{d}x\sim\delta_{mn},\quad m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.
\end{equation}
But if we integrate the equation $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(nx)$ with $x$ on $[0,\pi]$, we can obtain
\begin{equation}
C=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n,
\end{equation}
where $C=\int_0^\pi f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is a constant and $b_n=\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\mathrm{d}x$ is a series of constants. It seems like we have a number of optional $a_n$ to satisfy $C=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ such as
\begin{equation}
a_n\equiv\frac{C}{2^n b_n}.
\end{equation}
But this result conflicts with the correct result $a_n=\frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(nx)\mathrm{d}x}$. What's wrong?

Comment: Remember that $C$ is different to $f(x)$. Your first sum gives you coefficients that when summed give you $f(x)$ for all $x$. Your second sum gives you coefficients that when summed give you the constant number $C$.

Comment: And of course when trying to represent a *number* $C$ as a weighted sum of the *numbers* $b_n$, there is not going a unique set of $a_n$. There will be infinitely many choices of $a_n$ which will let you sum the $b_n$ to get $C$.

Comment: $C=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ is only  a necessary condition.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nb_n$ does not imply $(a_n)_{n\ge1}=(x_n)_{n\ge1}.$